Unable to load dynamic Data in ML.net
I have input data as List<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>
I want to load this data as Enumerable in MLContext
var mlContext = new MLContext();

mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(inputData);

I also have no way of predefining a strong static class for input data as everytime data columns will change
in dataView i get column schema as 0 when loaded
while transformation I get no column found exception
I have tried creating dynamic strong typed class
Genereated schema defination and loading the data
I wanted to transform column using loaded data

Any reason it's dynamic and not able to be as a string or float type?

My data comes from a API, Query execution or Email, I am using it for ETL, so at compile time I will never know what data will come, it is always List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> even it the data is made List<Dictionary<string, string>> it doesn't work.

Found the solution we have to invoke the method from reflection for it to work
        var typedInputDataList = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.Cast))
        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { inputDataList });
    var typedEnumerable = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.ToList))
        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { typedInputDataList });

    var loadFromEnumerableMethod = typeof(DataOperationsCatalog)
                        .GetMethods()
                        .Where(m => m.Name == "LoadFromEnumerable")
                        .First()
                        .MakeGenericMethod(type);
    MLContext mlContext = new();

    IDataView dataView = (IDataView)loadFromEnumerableMethod.Invoke(mlContext.Data, new object[] { typedEnumerable, schemaDefination });

